# How to use concat the right way in my mySQL to get the percentages of which tools have been registered the most

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I would like to have some statistics and calculate the percentages of which tools have been chosen the most overall in all the registrations of my database

These are my two tables:

```
$table_registration = $wpdb->prefix . 'registration';
$table_tools = $wpdb->prefix . 'tools';
```

**wp_registration table**:

```
CREATE TABLE $table_registration
(
    reg_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    dato date,
    billedeURL VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    fiske_vaegt DECIMAL( 2,1 ) NOT NULL,
    fiske_laengde INT NOT NULL,         
    reg_user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    reg_tools_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL

    PRIMARY KEY (reg_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (reg_user_id) REFERENCES wp_users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (reg_tools_id) REFERENCES $table_tools(tools_id) 
)
```

**wp_tools table**:

```
CREATE TABLE $table_tools
(
    tools_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    tools_navn CHAR (20),

    PRIMARY KEY (tools_id)
)
```

I have been trying to create the correct mysql but with no luck so this is what I've been doing up till now.

```
select l.*, concat(round(100 * count(t.reg_tools_id) / t2.cnt,0),'%')
from wp_registration l
left join wp_tools t on l.toolss_id = t.reg_id
cross join 
    (select count(*) cnt
     from wp_registration
     where reg_tools_id = 1) t2
group by l.reg_id;
```

But it tells me that every tool has been used 50% of the times. which obviously is wrong I have three tools users can choose from and right now have 1 - two votes and 2 - nine votes and 3 - two votes there are 13 registrations in total

Comment: can you please edit the part where you have the tables with Show CREATE table for both tables, so it is easy for us to work with is, and give us some data with the final result you want ..

Comment: okay :) just tell me if you need more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, I understand what do you need !

```
SELECT 
    tools.tools_id,
    ((COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM registration)) * 100) AS percent  
FROM 
    registration 
JOIN 
    tools ON registration.reg_tools_id = tools.tools_id
GROUP BY 
    tools.tools_id
ORDER BY 
    percent DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Some remarks :

- Try to write in a pure sql
- You do not need a php tag for this question
- Minimize your code from unnecessary part
- Use the concat and round functions in the programming language that you are using not in SQL (I think you are using php here, so do the query then get the result and apply the round and the concat in php instructions)